# File in Database Object POJO (Springboot)

Tags: java, file, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Say I have a SQL DO named "Team" that has a name, description, id, and profile picture.

It would look something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Team")
public class TeamDO implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="team_id")
    private Long id;
    private String description;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable = false)
    private Users users;

    public TeamDO() {}

    public TeamDO(Users user) {
        this.setUsers(user);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "TeamDO[id=%d, inital='%s', description='%s', name='%s']"
                , getId()
                , getUsers().getInitialName()
                , getDescription()
                , getName()
        );
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Users getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Users users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

What kind of variable stores a file such as a jpg? Or would my POJO have a String profilePictureURL which would be used to fetch the image (logo) for each team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's preferred to store the file in a hosting service of some sort and save only the URL in the DB but you can also save it as a byte array.

Comment: Thanks. I was just looking for a convention. Makes sense to store the URLs in the DB and use something like Amazon Web Services to host the files...

Comment: The convention is as you mentioned, usually you store only a URL of the uploaded file. As for your question to what kind of variable you need to store a file such as JPG, the answer is a byte array.